# how to add textarea data to my SQL database

Tags: php, html, database, forms, textarea

i have tried this code but it is not working .
this is db pic where the textarea is TechInfo and Notes.[techinfo and notes are tinytext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXZac.png). and this the php code :

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','deanship_of_information_technology');
    if(!$conn)
    {
    die(mysqli_error());
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
     $textareaValue = trim($_POST['information']);
      $sql="INSERT INTO technical_support(ApplicantName, BuildingNo, FloorNo, 
      EXTPhone,  ReportDate,  PlaceOfApp, TechInfo,Notes)VALUES('".inputName."','".inputBuilding."','".inputFloor."','".inputEXT."','".inputDateS."','".inputApp."','".$textareaValue."','".$textareaValue1."')";
    $rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $affectedRows = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);

    if($affectedRows == 1)
    {
        $successMsg = "Record has been saved successfully";
    }

    }
    ?>
```

this is php massage code :

```
    <?php
  if(isset($successMsg))
  {
    echo "<div class='success-msg'>";
    print_r($successMsg);
    echo "</div>";
  }
?>
```

this is the html form code where i want the sucss msg to be in the same massage  :

```
     <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
      <br> <br><br> <img class="mb-4" src="/Users/ahadalmalki/Desktop/web-1 2/img/logo1.png" alt="" width="100" height="120">
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputName"><b> Applicant Name:</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" align="left" name="inputName" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputBuilding"><b> Building Number :</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Building#" align="left" name="inputBuilding" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputFloor"><b>Floor Number:</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Floor#" name="inputFloor" class="form-control" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEXT"><b>EXT Phone:</b></label>
      <input type="phone" placeholder="EXT Phone" align="left" name="inputEXT" class="form-control" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputDateS"><b> Date:</b></label>
      <input type="date" placeholder="Date" align="left" name="inputDateS" class="form-control" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputApp"><b>Place Of Application  :</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Place Of Application" name="inputApp" class="form-control" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputinfo"><b>Technical Support Information :</b> </label><br>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="89" name="information" form="form-signin" required>
</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputNotes"><b>Notes:</b></label><br>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="75" name="Notes" form="form-signin" required>
      </textarea>
      </div>


      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
```

i want the information to be added to the database but the error comes out information and notes are undefined index and the other as inputname inputapp ... error comes out like :use of an undefined constant will throw an error in the future .

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is in here:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="89" name="information" form="form-signin" required>
</textarea>
```

You have

> form="form-signin"

attributes, i think it should be class attribute

Comment: great ,, worked i put . class="form-control".thankyou

Comment: there +1, not sure why they downvote me too, it was a legit answer!

Answer (score -1):

first of all verify the variables in your query (they don´t have "$" before and you are not assigning any value to them), second, before you execute any query, print it out, copy it and run it directly in your database client, this will help you to find if there´s any error in the query you built also try this query instead, remember always to make sure you are receiving the textarea information in your $_POST (a print_r() will do before any query execution)

```
$textareaValue = trim($_POST['information']);
  $sql="INSERT INTO technical_support SET ApplicantName = $inputName, 
        BuildingNo = $inputBuilding, FloorNo = $inputFloor, EXTPhone = $inputEXT, 
        ReportDate = $inputDateS, PlaceOfApp = $inputApp, TechInfo = $textareaValue, 
        Notes = $textareaValue1"
```

Let me know how it goes!